# MPMoviePlayer for streaming audio and keeping controls

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I'm using MPMoviePlayer to stream audio from a podcast and so far it's working great with the exception of the fact that the controls fade out after the audio begins playing as it would when you're watching a movie so I have a few questions:

1) Is it appropriate to use MPMoviePlayer, which seems to really be designed more for video than audio for streaming mp3 files?

2) If so, is there a way to keep the controls from fading out? I'm currently setting the control style:

```
[player setControlStyle: MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded];
```

Which appears to be, [according to Apple's docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MPMoviePlayerController/controlStyle), the correct style to keep the controls on screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Is it appropriate to use MPMoviePlayer, which seems to really be designed more for video than audio for streaming mp3 files?*

Yes, even though there certainly are other options - have a look at `AVPlayer` for example. But then again, that won't show any UI at all so the next answer will in any case apply: you will have to build you own UI if you are not satisfied with the one `MPMoviePlayerController` has to offer (even though in your particular case it is just the fade-out).

> *If so, is there a way to keep the controls from fading out? I'm currently setting the control style:*

No, there is no way to achieve what you are asking for when using the standard UI (no matter if embedded or fullscreen). The only option would be supplying custom controls (while using `MPMovieControlStyleNone`).